# Mule soap consumer filters envelope

Tags: mule

From soap consumer, I am getting response without soap env, but I need response in soap env.

My code:

```
<flow name="mws-api-intFlow"> 
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="pocreate" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
              %output application/xml
                ---
              payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="PO-Create" operation="MIOut_Sync_WSDL_WSPurchaseOrderPushRequestMessage" doc:name="Web_Service-POCreate"/>  
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>       
    </flow>
```

it returns following response:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
    <ns1:PurchaseOrderExportReply xmlns:ns1="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vsap" partition="prealm_2068" variant="vrealm_2068">
        <ns1:Requisition_PurchImport_Item>
            <ns1:item>
                <ns1:LineItems>
                    <ns1:item>
                        <ns1:ERPPONumber>7133</ns1:ERPPONumber>
                        <ns1:NumberInCollection>1</ns1:NumberInCollection>
                        <ns1:PODeliveryDate>2014-04-27T00:00:00AribaBuyerTimeZone</ns1:PODeliveryDate>
                        <ns1:POQuantity>10.000</ns1:POQuantity>
                        <ns1:POUnitPrice>10.00</ns1:POUnitPrice>
                        <ns1:SAPPOLineNumber>00001</ns1:SAPPOLineNumber>
                    </ns1:item>
                </ns1:LineItems>
                <ns1:UniqueName>Test</ns1:UniqueName>
            </ns1:item>
        </ns1:Requisition_PurchImport_Item>
    </ns1:PurchaseOrderExportReply>
```

While debugging enabled, i found that response comes with soap env but it displays only body part in xml format:

```
    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Header />
   <SOAP:Body>
      <ns1:Requisition_PurchImport_Item xmlns:ns1="urn:Ariba:Buyer:vsap" partition="prealm_2068" variant="vrealm_2068">
         <ns1:Requisition_PurchOrdNumberImport_Item>
            <ns1:item>
               <ns1:LineItems>
                  <ns1:item>
                     <ns1:ERPPONumber>7133</ns1:ERPPONumber>
                     <ns1:NumberInCollection>1</ns1:NumberInCollection>
                     <ns1:PODeliveryDate>2017-04-27T00:00:00AribaBuyerTimeZone</ns1:PODeliveryDate>
                     <ns1:POQuantity>10.000</ns1:POQuantity>
                     <ns1:POUnitPrice>10.00</ns1:POUnitPrice>
                     <ns1:SAPPOLineNumber>00001</ns1:SAPPOLineNumber>
                  </ns1:item>
               </ns1:LineItems>
               <ns1:UniqueName>PR39</ns1:UniqueName>
            </ns1:item>
         </ns1:Requisition_PurchOrdNumberImport_Item>
      </ns1:Requisition_PurchImport_Item>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I want to get this response, how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Consumer expects to receive just the **body** payload to it will add the SOAP envelope parts by itself and will produce a response without envelope.
The web-service-consumer is designed to **only accept** the body/operation part of the XML document and will produce body/operation in response.

So what you are getting is expected. pls refer the doc:- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/web-service-consumer
You need Dataweave to create your complete response with Envelope

What you can do here use XSLT transformer or DataWeave to add your soap envelope after your  in the response something like following example :-

```
<ws:consumer config-ref="PO-Create" operation="MIOut_Sync_WSDL_WSPurchaseOrderPushRequestMessage" doc:name="Web_Service-POCreate"/>  

    <dw:transform-message doc:name="XMLSoapRes" >
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="ListInventoryResponse.xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
%namespace ns0 http://yournamespace/tshirt-service
%namespace soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
---
soap#Envelope : {

soap#Body:payload

}]]></dw:set-payload>
  </dw:transform-message>
```

Comment: this is like hard coding soap env and headers? how about receiving soap headers?

Comment: You cannot expect SOAP envelope with web service consumer component.. If you want full SOAP response with envelope and body, then use HTTP request component to post your SOAP request directly and get SOAP response with envelope... With web service consumer, you need to manually add the envelope with Dataweave or XSLT .. may be hardcoded as you say